Can this circular 10-pin connector be identified (in the hopes of finding a better equivalent)?
This connector is used on Oxford Instruments cryostats.  I can get spares, but it would be nice to overcome some of the shortcomings if there's something compatible .  There's text "M10S" but that doesn't lead to anything helpful when paired with relevant search terms.

The hexagon (slightly damaged here) is 14.3mm (9/16") AF and screws into the round body. The pin spacing isn't uniform but the smallest is just under 4mm.
On the back, pins are identified with letters rather than numbers (and they can't be sequential as K would be 11).

The whole connector is only 26mm long, which leaves <10mm between the end of the pins and the cable clamp - not enough for heatshrink but a short is likely to cause damage to the cryostat or the experiment in it.  The clamp also doesn't do much in the way of strain relief. We've overcome this by 3d-printing a strain relieving extension to the shell (not shown, but that's why the wires are left so long in the picture below), attaching in place of the cable clamp, but a longer body and better strain relief would be helpful.  It's common to run multiple coax cables in there and they always break.  So it's memorably annoying to work with.

Another unusual feature is that the only contact is the pins.  The mating part is either soldered into a tube (as highlighted below) or O-ring sealed with a surround that doesn't support the plug.  This is the vacuum seal for the cryostat so can't be changed without major work.


If customers end up 3d-printing strain relief for a connector, it's probably not very good in the first place.  We also have to hold the original cable into the connector by strapping it with cable ties or it breaks contact (sometime only on some pins causing very strange misbehaviour). But that doesn't help identify it, and I doubt there's any way to completely replace it

Is that M105, or MIOS, or MI05, or M10S, or some other combination of letters and numbers?

This looks like the sort of connector that would be accompanied with a threaded outer ring to lock the sides together, much like a 7 mm connector. Is the outer part of the plug threaded, and the socket perhaps missing a sleeve that's supposed to be there?

@Hearth I wish that was the case. I've got some brand new ones turning up in a couple of days, and I'll also be in a position to get better pictures of both models of cryostat  demonstrating that there's nothing on that side. M10S I believe (the macro lens did a better job than my magnifying glass but I've rechecked), and 10 makes sense from the number of pins. M105 is possible. Again I'll check the new ones in case it's clearer

If I'd hung on for my delivery, the new ones are labelled GH-10F and among other things the correct part is found - unlike with the one I had in my hand (partly @Hearth).  They're supplied with a rubber tube as strain relief, lacking any flange or taper to hold it in place

My Identiconn utility identified that as a circle-hex connector.
It was common in scientific instrumentation in the 1970's. It is a rare example of a connector that is shroudless yet it is latched. It's practically obsolete but you can still buy it:

MANUF. - SERIES
WPI - 126 series (pdf) - newark
Positronic - GH Positronic (5+ ckt) (pdf)
Cooper Industries made them as the 126 series, but Eaton acquired them and now that line of products seems to be gone.

Upon further search, I see that the standard connectors go up to 9 contacts. Yours has 10 contacts.  But Positronic does have a 10-circuit one! The part number is GH10.

https://www.verical.com/pd/positronic-circular-GH10FSCLRH16-10194280
https://uk.farnell.com/positronic/gh10fsclrh16/mini-circular-hex-s-10-pos-st/dp/4082197

You may find them from surplus vintage stores or eBay.

I did have a good look  on (apparently the old version of) your Identiconn, without any luck - spottoing a link to it in an old answer of yours was what prompted me to look into it. The Microstat design is at least that old (and the Positronic catalogue not much newer by the style of it). That makes for a strange hybrid of metric fasteners and imperial dimensions, some of which only make sense in a way that gives an insight into what order the draughtsman worked on the design.  Such a shame that locking versions exist but they chose not to use them.

I can get them from a specialist supplier for about 1/3 of what Farnell charge (or similar to Verical), but the non-locking version.  But now you've identified it and I have a full part number via Verical, I see a few suppliers (though not many selling singly.  My suspicions that a better version existed are confirmed.

The wires going into the connector do not appear to be carrying high voltage/current or data with special requirements so if you are looking for a replacement then general purpose connectors should work (if you have information otherwise then things will change of course).
Unfortunately, there are not a lot of good options for bare wires going into a connector. We can't talk about specific product lines here (not to say you can't use them) but standardized connector families such as M12, 5015, or 38999 could work. Putting a heat shrink tube around the wire bundle can help get an acceptable level of strain relief; some of the milspec connectors have backshells that are designed for bare wire bundling but finding something for just a few small wires could be tricky or prohibitively expensive. Adhesive lined heat shrink tubing can also help circularize a lumpy wire bundle.
If you want to do it the "right" way, then I would rewire everything going into the plug so as to use jacketed cable and select a connector with a strain relief compatible with the OD of the new cabling.
NB: "I" is frequently omitted from connector pin identification as it can be confused with "1" or "l". Ditto O/o/0.

I thought I made it clear that  the other side can't be replaced (because it's soldered in to the tube or an O-ring seal).  I'll edit to be even more explicit.

I assembled that one today for up to about 300mA peak, pulsed at 0.1%, <10V which is typical for us.  The cryostat manufacturer uses a pair of pins for 1A at 40V for the heater.  We generally try to take coax as close as possible because of the effect on the edges of the pulse - ringing is undesirable - but I'm going to run some tests using a chopped up VGA cable  before looking into multi-coax options.  This is a short length of screened twisted pair to a breakout box, Even glue-lined heatshrink has failed before and makes rework harder.  However combined with the 3d-printed part I'm hopeful

They also omit G (on all the related designs, it turns out, probably too similar to C with the most minor damage), and it goes up to L
